# Sorting networks costs and delay

Tags: sorting, sorting-network

From what I read I could not figure out how the cost and delay are calculated.

- Cost: the number of sticks or compare-exchange blocks.
- Delay: the number of compare-exchanges in sequence.

I have posted my example bellow [image: Example]

Comment: As an additional note, what you call *cost* and *delay* are often known as *size* and *depth*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, your answer is correct.

**Cost** is the total number compare exchanges done in the sorting network. I believe here it's 28.

**Delay** is the number of stages that must be done in sequence, i.e. have data dependencies. In the example there is a delay of 13.

Why do we care about the difference? Cost represents the amount of work we have to do in a serial implementation *however* the benefit of using a sorting network is that many of the compare-exchanges can be done in parallel. When you have as much parallelism available as there are compare-exchanges in a single stage, you can calculate that stage concurrently.

In a perfectly parallel system, the latency of the algorithm is going to be related to the delay rather than the cost. In a completely serial system, the latency is going to be related to the cost rather than the delay.

Comment: So is it correct to understand that the delay is the maximum number of comparisons that can be done in a sequence?

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't sound quite right. Let's say that your sorting network is defined by nodes and stages. A node is a point where a compare-and-exchange operation is done. A stage is a set of nodes that can be executed concurrently. Cost is the number of nodes. Delay is the number of stages.

Comment: Good enough for me. You can add this comment as part of your answer, hepefully it will help some one else too. Thank you for your help! I

Comment: Is the delay calculated for each input or is it calculated for "worst case" ?
Meaning, if the input would be 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 will the delay be 1?

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu Actually, sorting networks are a bit of a phenomenon in that they don't have a worst-case/best-case performance. Any permutation of the input array will have the exact same complexity and this is one of its strongest features. The algorithm behaviour is fixed ahead of time and therefore the performance is extremely predictable and reproducible.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu One weakness is that you need a different sorting network for every input size N. If you wanted to reuse the network in your example to sort, say, five values, you would need to append your input with three dummy values and run it with the same cost-delay as the eight-value input. Alternatively you could generate a different network optimised for five values.